# Tell a ViewGroup to center itself in *remaining* space

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two ViewGroups in a layout; I want one of them (FOO, which contains several text fields) to be pinned against the bottom of the parent view (the layout itself).  This is easy, no problem with this.

I want the other ViewGroup (BAR, containing an image and a text field) to be centered (vertically) in the *remaining* space left above FOO:

```
-----------------
|               |
|               |
|               |
|   ---------   |
|   |  BAR  |   | <- floating, centered vertically in the remaining space
|   ---------   |
|               |
|               |
|               |
|   ---------   |
|   |  FOO  |   | <- pinned to the bottom
|   ---------   |
-----------------
```

It seems simple enough, but this is the part that I can't quite seem to summon the voodoo to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to nest BAR inside another RelativeLayout positioned above FOO, with height and width equal to match parent. Then you center BAR within this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <!--foo views-->
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/remaining_space"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/foo">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">
            <!--bar views-->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this pseduo-layout will serve your purpose. The main idea is wrapping BAR and FOO in relative layouts and then specifying how each one should be placed.

```
<RelativeLayout 
 android:id="@+id/relative_parent"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <RelativeLayout 
      android:id="@+id/relative_foo"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

     <RelativeLayout 
      android:id="@+id/relative_bar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
      android:layout_above="@+id/relative_foo" >

           <ViewGroup 
             android:id="@+id/viewgroup_bar"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```